# jQuery / Javascript boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that I am working with where the user can choose to download a "Slice" of a pie chart or the whole thing.

When they click on a slice, I send a variable called `source` which tells me which slice it came from.

Right now I am working on the "Download All" button. The source for this will be simply `all`.

This is what my loop looks like if the user selects `slice`:

```
// Loop over our data
$.each(seed.dataset,function(key, value){
   if(this[col] == slice){
      table += '<tr>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escalationID+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escReasonID+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.reasonText+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escCreatedBy+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorFirst+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorLast+'</td>';
      table += '</tr>';
  }
});
```

The `IF` statement within the loop is what controls the data its including in the table variable. My question is, how can I choose when I want to enforce this IF statement or ignore it (allowing all data to be added to the table var)?

The obvious would be wrapping it in another IF statement but I feel there might be a cleaner way without having to duplicate all of the table data.

End result would be a `bool` saying `if source=All` include all the rows `else if source=slice` enforce the IF statement to include only the data we are looking for.

**UPDATE**

Essentially I am looking for a more clean way to do this:

```
// Loop over our data
    $.each(seed.dataset,function(key, value){

      if(source == 'slice'){

        if(this[col] == slice){
           table += '<tr>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escalationID+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escReasonID+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.reasonText+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escCreatedBy+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorFirst+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorLast+'</td>';
           table += '</tr>';
       }

      // We are downloading all so ignore the constraint 
      }else{
           table += '<tr>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escalationID+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escReasonID+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.reasonText+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escCreatedBy+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorFirst+'</td>';
           table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorLast+'</td>';
           table += '</tr>';
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another boolean say `ignoreAll` as "OR" condition with existing if condition as shown below

```
// Loop over our data
var ignoreAll = true; // change its value as per your requirement
$.each(seed.dataset,function(key, value){
   if(ignoreAll || this[col] == slice){
      table += '<tr>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escalationID+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escReasonID+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.reasonText+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escCreatedBy+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorFirst+'</td>';
      table += '<td>'+this.escCreatorLast+'</td>';
      table += '</tr>';
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm adding this in right now to test it but from what I can tell, if `ignoreAll` is false, none of the data would be included?

Comment: if `ignoreAll` is false it will check `this[col] == slice` condition because it is in OR mode and not AND mode. if second conditon is true then it will add row to table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(seed.dataset,function(key, value){
      if (source != 'slice'  ||  this[col] == slice){
           table += '<tr>';
           // etc.
```

Alternatively:

```
$.each(seed.dataset,function(key, value){
      if (source == 'all'  ||  this[col] == slice){
           table += '<tr>';
           // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below code.

If the current item is a slice, it's checked to make sure it is the correct slice. If it is, `getSlice()` is called and the `$.each()` loop breaks to avoid unnecessary iterations.

```
function getSlice(that) {
    var table = '';
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>' + that.escalationID + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + that.escReasonID + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + that.reasonText + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + that.escCreatedBy + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + that.escCreatorFirst + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + that.escCreatorLast + '</td>';
    table += '</tr>';
    return table;
}

// Loop over our data
$.each(seed.dataset, function (key, value) {
    table += source == 'slice' ? (this[col] == slice ? true & getSlice(this) : false) : getSlice(this);
    if (table === true) return false; // break out of loop
});
```